# I tried making a discord bot but i got this error while trying to activate it

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, syntax-error, bots

[This is the problem i get while trying to use the node discord .js command idk how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM0Bg.png)

Comment: All your "double" single quotes should be single. Replace every `''` with `'` or with `"`.

Comment: I agree with @ZsoltMeszaros. For the future please inform yourself [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly and not just post a screenshot. Show what you tried, describe the error and maybe already bring possible solution suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Select the entirety of everything that is selected in the red lines and press the actual quotation. This encapsulates it into a quotation mark. Repeat for all the other ones.

So for example, your first line `const Discord = require(''discord.js'')`

=> Needs to be changed into `const Discord = require('discord.js')`

Also, if you do want the quotations to be printed, you could use

`console.log('\'hi\'')`. This prints the quotations around your message in your console.

Comment: i tried it but i get the same error, i'll see if i can find a solution for this xD i'm new with these things A

Comment: It's because you're only fixing what I detailed in the example, you have to apply it to all the other red lines.